# How do you declare a the "nbsp" entity in XML document

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, freemarker

I am getting the following error

The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared.

I tried to declare the nbsp (shown below) in my XML file. But this isn't working for me.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <rss version="2.0"
   xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
   xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
  >
  <!DOCTYPE html [<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
```

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Doctypes have to go between the XML declaration and the root element. (And you can't have a Doctype claiming the root element is `html` when it is actually `rss`). You should probably just use numeric character references or actual non-breaking spaces instead of dropping HTML into the middle of your RSS though.

Comment: Well, I'm using freemarker to parse the XML data. Within my XML file there is  "<p>&nbsp;</p>" which isn't recognized. Any suggestions?

Comment: "You should probably just use numeric character references or actual non-breaking spaces"

Comment: Thanks but &nbsp; is automatically outputted in the XML I need to replace it with &#160;

Comment: Fix the tool that is generating the invalid XML then.

Answer (score 5):

Put the DOCTYPE declaration before the root element start-tag. That is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html [
   <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
]>
<rss version="2.0"
  xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
  xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
 >
 ...
</rss>
```